# How to make Table Layout Screen independent

Tags: java, android

1.This is my code where i m trying to display a matrix of buttons with the help of    table layout .and i have also tried to make this matrix screen independent but this is not working properly.in large size emulator it is giving problem buttons getting overlapped.

```
     TableLayout layout = new TableLayout (this);
     layout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
     Display display = ((WindowManager)       getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
           int width = display.getWidth();  
           int height = display.getHeight();
           layout.setLayoutParams( new TableLayout.LayoutParams(height,width) );

            layout.setPadding(1,1,1,1);

            for (int f=0; f<=3; f++) 
            {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);

                for (int c=0; c<=3; c++) 
                {
                    Button b = new Button (this);
                    b.setText(""+f+c);
                    b.setTextSize(10.0f);
                    b.setTextColor(Color.rgb( 100, 200, 200));



                  tr.addView(b,30,30);


                    final float scale = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                    int pixels = (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);
                     b.setHeight(pixels);
                     b.setWidth(pixels);


                } // for
                layout.addView(tr);
            } // for

            super.setContentView(layout);
        } 

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the layout parameters in a weird way. Try using:

```
layout.setLayoutParams( new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

The same problem with the Buttons. Try using this:

```
Button b = new Button (this);

LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER; // if you want it centered
params.span = 1;

b..setLayoutParams(params);

b.setText(""+f+c);
b.setTextSize(10.0f);
b.setTextColor(Color.rgb( 100, 200, 200));

tr.addView(b);
```

And don't set the height and width values using the "scale".
The `params.span = 1;` part should give the same width to every element in your table row.
And `params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;` will center it in the table cell.

Or you could use GridLayout. See it here: [New Layout Widgets: Space and GridLayout](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html)

Comment: @PareshMayani Thanks paresh as i m beginner your solution helped me alot

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with TableLayout, but you could a LinearLayout to make the buttons the same size. You could have one vertical LinearLayout wrapping 4 horizontal LinearLayouts, which each have 4 buttons with the same layout weight inside.

Example LinearLayout: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html